# C# ASPX CheckListbox where are the values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASPX C# page with a `CheckListBox`. 
Using the following code to determine if the item is checked and it is always false.

```
if (lstFiles.Items[i].Selected)
```

I have tried `lstFiles.Items[i].CheckedItems`, but that is not a valid attribute. I also tried
I have tried `lstFiles.Items[i].SelectedItems`, but that is not a valid attribute either.

I think VS2010 is confused, but I don't know where.

----Ok, they click on a box in my CheckBoxList control and all that should happen is the box is checked waiting for them to select another item.  The user then click the Delete Button and this code is executed.

```
`protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         foreach (ListItem i in lstFiles.Items)
         {
             if (i.Selected)
             {
                 string filename = i.Value.ToString();
                 DeleteFTP(filename);
             }
         }

        string[] filenames = GetFileList();
        lstFiles.Items.Clear();


        foreach (string filenamel in filenames)
        {
            lstFiles.Items.Add(filenamel);
        }
     }`
```

--- in all cases i.Selected = False, I have 2 items with one of them checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As glosrob said, simple way to check all CheckBoxList tiems is this:

```
foreach (ListItem i in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (i.Selected)
    { 
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

It looks like the fact that you don't work with this control itself, but with its items, confused you. So you can't look if the CheckBoxList is checked or selected:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">a</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">b</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">c</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: The type or NameSpace "ListIem" is not found.

Comment: The i.Selected is saying False. i has the correct value of what i checked, but i.selected is false

Comment: ListItem is in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.
Could you give us the part of code you are using? 
In what event are you checking its state?

Comment: I figured out what is happening, just have to figure out how to make it work right.  When I Click the Delete button is seam to fire the page_load event.  I put in the page_load event code to load my CheckBox list, I put it there so that it was filled in when the page came up.  Just need to find a onetime event for startup of the page.

Comment: Page_load event is firing on every PostBack. When you click on your Delete button, Page_load event happens before btnDelete_Click. If you want to set some values at the first loading of the page, put it inside Page_load event like this:
    
    if(!isPostBack)
    {
        //set starting values here
    }

Code inside this block wil run at first load only.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - I see you are using a web control.

The following is working for me:
Markup

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test 2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test 3" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Go!" OnClick="btnTest_click" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btnTest_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListItem li in checkBoxList1.Items)
   {
       if (li.Selected)
       {
           //item is selected
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: the only events/Actions I have are SelectedIndexChanged, TextChanged.  Nothing talking about checked?

Comment: Well that is a slightly different question: when do you need to get the information on what is checked and what isn't?

Comment: yes, but like I said I don't see any attributes with the word "check" in it.  I dropped the control and put it back on and still nothing.

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" 
        Width="601px">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: neiter of these two options work `foreach (var item in lstFiles.Items)
             {
                 if (item.Selected)
                 {
                 }
             }


            for (int i=0; i<lstFiles.Items.Count; i++)
            {
            if (lstFiles.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    string filename = lstFiles.Items[i].Value.ToString();
                    DeleteFTP(filename);
                }
            }`----Item.Selected not and attribute

Comment: When are you running your loop? In other words, what event do you invoke to run the code you have posted?

Comment: To use the Checkbox's do I need to have Postback = true?  Because when i had it as True my checks went away.